# How to parse this result

Tags: python, parsing, telegram, telethon

I want to get the `id` and `first_name` of a user using the `GetContactsRequest` method from the Telethon library so that I can send a message using that `id` without having to hard code the `id` of every contact I have. This is the code

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

with TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.contacts.GetContactsRequest(
        hash=0
    ))
    print(result.stringify())
```

This is the output of result.stringify()

```
Contacts(
    contacts=[
        Contact()
        Contact()
    ]
    users=[
        User(
            id = xxx
            first_name = 'name'
        ),
        User(
            id = xxx
            first_name = 'name'
        )
    ]
)
```

The problem is I am not sure how to parse this, Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the documentation for `Contacts` [here](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/contacts/contacts.html). Basically, all you need to do is iterate over the users and access `id` for each user.

```py
for user in result.users:
    print (user.id, user.first_name)
```